# I'm trying to remove the background of an image

Tags: python, opencv

How can I remove the white background of an image with a code?
I've tried this, but didn't work:

```
import cv2

RED =0
GREEN =0
BLUE =0
ALPHA =0

Image = cv2.imread("D:\\PYTHON_bkground\\bkg\\sagitale1.png", cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)

trans_mask = Image[:,:,3 ]==0

Image[trans_mask]=[BLUE, GREEN, RED, ALPHA]

print(Image.shape)
resized = cv2.resize(Image, None, fx=0.1, fy=0.1)
cv2.imshow('windows', resized)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

this error appears: `Traceback (most recent call last): File "d:\PYTHON_bkg1\bkg\bkg.py", line 12, in <module> trans_mask = Image[:,:,3 ]==0 TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable`

[image]

Comment: I noticed you added an image but didn't actually link it or anything, so I edited and showed it. If you'd like to make any changes, you can [edit]. For help, see [Markdown help](/editing-help). BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] if you want tips.

Comment: imread failed. look for previous questions on that. -- you need to post THE WHOLE error, not just the last line of it. that stuff is not optional.

Comment: Thanks for the help. i'm new here

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the white background easily using pillow module python as follows.

```
from PIL import Image


def convertImage():
    img = Image.open("d.png")
    img = img.convert("RGBA")
  
    datas = img.getdata()
  
    newData = []
  
    for item in datas:
        if item[0] == 255 and item[1] == 255 and item[2] == 255:
            newData.append((255, 255, 255, 0))
        else:
            newData.append(item)
  
    img.putdata(newData)
    img.save("pic.png", format="png")
  
convertImage()
```

[image]